# Limits when delta is small

Tags: calculus, limits

For limits, why do we only care about delta that is small when the definition of the limit does not mention that at all?

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you talk about limits, you talk about something that is local instead of global, because you want to analyse the behaviour of the function close to the limit point, not far away. Probably always it's close to the point that the problems are. So, if you want to take $\varepsilon = 100$, that usually will not guarantee or show anything interesting about the behaviour of your function, but if you take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{100}$, then you probably will start to see some problems, if they exist.

Comment: Well, I not mentioned $\delta$, but in real life it's always smaller than $\varepsilon$, so the answer still apply.